# Why doesn't Java Core Reflection open any factory to allow creation of reflective objects for java generics?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Java 10 has a special `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects` package containing classes such as `GenericArrayTypeImpl`, `ParameterizedTypeImpl` and others. Also, the `sun.reflect.generics.factory.GenericsFactory` can be used to instantiate classes implementing `GenericArrayType`, `ParameterizedType`, ...

There are many libraries (guava, apache, guice, spring, ...)  with their own hierarchy of classes implementing these interfaces to deal with custom generic types. What's the reason to not open a generics factory infrastructure to creators of libraries dealing with generics objects?

Adding an 'Add-Opens' manifest entry to the library jar doesn't solve the problem due to this mechanism is designed to be used only with executable JARs.

Comment: I think this part of the API is pretty under-developed in general. There are also no specifications for `equals` and `hashCode`, and no implementation of the subtyping algorithm, among other shortcomings.